# center text on image

Tags: html, css

This is probably very easy to do, but for some reason, nothing is working form me. Lets say I have an image and a text like so:

```
<div id="my_div">
    <img src="my_img.png" alt="Test" />
    <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

How do I center the text `Some Text` horizontally and vertically on my image (I want the text to appear in the middle of the image)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table/table-cell`:

CSS:

```css
.example {
    display: table;
    width: 100px; /* Width of the image */
    height: 100px; /* Height of the image */
}

.example > P {
    background: url(my_img.png) no-repeat;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center; /* Center text horizontally. */
    vertical-align: middle; /* Center text vertically. */
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="example"><p>
    Some text
</p></div>
```

If you need to have your image as `IMG` element, you can use similar code with addition of `IMG` element before it and negative `margin-top` for element with `display:table` to position text above image.

Comment: Note that is not supported by IE7/IE8

Comment: @Raul: No, `display: table` _is_ supported in IE8+. IE7 almost does not matter currently.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this that works in virtually all browsers is to make the image the background image of the div and then set the line-height property of the paragraph. Note that this only really works if the text is on one line.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/29Bee/1)**

**CSS**

```
#my_div p {
    line-height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}

#my_div {
    background-image: url(http://www.placekitten.com/400/200);
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="my_div">
    <p>Some Text</p>
</div>​
```